# How can I apply histwords to my own corpus of text?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, word2vec

I recently come across this paper ( https://arxiv.org/pdf/1605.09096.pdf ) and I have been Reading through the GitHub ( https://github.com/williamleif/histwords ) but it is still not so clear to me how I can apply it to my own data. My data comes in the format of the following:

```
#### 2008
   text_2008 = pd.DataFrame({'dat1': ["I love machine learning in 2008. Its awesome.",
            "I love coding in Python in 2008",
            "I love building chatbots in 2008",
            "they chat amagingly well"]})
    ID_2008 = pd.DataFrame({'dat2': [1,2,3,4]})

    my_actual_data_format_2008 = text.join(ID)

#### 2009
   text_2009 = pd.DataFrame({'dat1': ["I love machine learning. Its awesome.",
            "I love coding in Python",
            "I love building chatbots",
            "they chat amagingly well"]})
    ID_2009 = pd.DataFrame({'dat2': [1,2,3,4]})

    my_actual_data_format_2009 = text.join(ID)


#### 2010
   text_2010 = pd.DataFrame({'dat1': ["I love machine learning more in 2010. Its awesome.",
            "I love coding in Python in 2010",
            "I love building chatbots in 2010",
            "they chat amagingly well"]})
    ID_2010 = pd.DataFrame({'dat2': [1,2,3,4]})

    my_actual_data_format_2010 = text.join(ID)
```

So I have multiple pandas data frames with each row containing an `ID` and `text` column.

From my understanding, the sgns takes .txt files not pandas data frames. ( https://github.com/williamleif/histwords/tree/master/sgns )

From the homepage it states "If you want to learn historical embeddings for new data, the code in the sgns directory is recommended"

If somebody can give me a push in the right direction, that would be awesome! Should I save my pandas rows "text" as .txt files?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this pipeline mentioned in the readme.

```
**DATA:**  raw corpus  =>  corpus  =>  pairs  =>  counts  =>  vocab  
**TRADITIONAL:**  counts + vocab  =>  pmi  =>  svd  
**EMBEDDINGS:**  pairs  + vocab  =>  sgns  

**raw corpus  =>  corpus**  
- *scripts/clean_corpus.sh*
- Eliminates non-alphanumeric tokens from the original corpus.

**corpus  =>  pairs**  
- *corpus2pairs.py*  
- Extracts a collection of word-context pairs from the corpus.

**pairs  =>  counts**  
- *scripts/pairs2counts.sh*
- Aggregates identical word-context pairs.

**counts  =>  vocab**  
- *counts2vocab.py*  
- Creates vocabularies with the words' and contexts' unigram distributions.

**counts + vocab  =>  pmi**  
- *counts2pmi.py*  
- Creates a PMI matrix (*scipy.sparse.csr_matrix*) from the counts.

**pmi  =>  svd**  
- *pmi2svd.py*  
- Factorizes the PMI matrix using SVD. Saves the result as three dense numpy matrices.

**pairs  + vocab  =>  sgns**  
- *word2vecf/word2vecf*
- An external program for creating embeddings with SGNS. For more information, see:  
**"Dependency-Based Word Embeddings". Omer Levy and Yoav Goldberg. ACL 2014.**

An example pipeline is demonstrated in: *example_test.sh*
```

from [here](https://github.com/williamleif/histwords/tree/master/sgns/hyperwords)